# Reg. Search engine optimization for my blog

Tags: asp.net-mvc, seo, search-engine

I'm on the way of creating a blog through ASP.NET MVC framework. All the articles I'm going to submit have the same layout only the main content differs. So I created a common view that dynamically loads the content from a physical file(contains only the particular article markup) in a section. So all the url requests send by users points to a same physical file that dynamically loads a particular section based upon the article. Is this the right approach? Is this create some problems in SEO? I'm eager to hear from you. **[UPDATED]** The urls of the articles look like http://myblog.com/blog/archives/2011/1/using_asp_mvc. All these kind of requests are received by a single page that loads the content of the article from another physical file in it.

Comment: Could you show a couple of examples of how your urls look like? This could be useful to someone answering a question about whether some routes are SEO friendly or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to rewrite the url like in

http://www.cricandcric.com/Cricket-News/4182/Cricket-West-Indies-:-I-am-sure-that-West-Indies-will-bounce-back-,-said-Hooper.html

If you obesrve this I have done the URL Rewriting, which will be user friendly for the search engines.

You can find good references at following url

http://www.webconfs.com/url-rewriting-tool.php

http://corz.org/serv/tricks/htaccess2.php

To make it more understandable about the power of url rewriting
if you search for "I am sure that West Indies will bounce back , said Hooper"
in google, you can see our cricandcric.com in the first page

Comment: Your page is listed first without doubt. In the urls you posted I see file extensions(.php) but in my case there are no file extensions(ex. http://myblog.com/blog/archives/2011/1/using_asp_mvc). Is this makes any difference in SEO?

Comment: @Vijaya, with url rewriting you can display anything you want, its not mandatory to have an extension. and it wont make any difference at all